# python/numpy/pandas fastest way apply algorithm for expanding calculations

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

lets say i have time-series starting from 1/1/2000 to 1/1/2011 and for each date, i have some float value..this is in a pandas dataframe.

i want to perform some calculation that is.  Assume N is the number of data points and i is the current data point. psuedo code:

```
for i in n:
        some_calc(V0:Vi) + some_calc(Vi:Vn)
```

I can easily implement this calculation, but seeing performance issues i think for large sets.  Part of it i think is that since the data container is a Dataframe, slicing creates new series and in some_calc, more slicing occurs.

What is an efficient way of doing something like the?  Can i avoid the loop by using numpy?

Comment: You can try putting all data into your dataframe and do row-wise transformation with `dataframe.apply`. This would avoid the `for loop`.

Comment: Some calculations can be vectorized and some can't.  This question can't be answered in general.  In numpy and pandas, though, slicing does not create an entirely new array, only a new view onto the original data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to increase your code performance:

```
result = []
for item in item_list:
    new_item = do_something_with(item)
    result.append(new_item)
```

See example below:

```
# finding the max prior to the current item
a = [3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 9, 0, 7, 5, 8]
results = []
current_max = 0
for i in a:
    current_max = max(i, current_max)
    results.append(current_max)
# results = [3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```